# How can I create my own card for my own game?

Tags: custom-game-pieces

I've created a set of rules for a card game I would like to test, but I have no clue on how to build my nice-looking cards.
Any hint on what program/site to use is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple prices of software that do this. A good list is available at http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/991506/resources-card-game-makers but rather than repeat those I'll say that beyond using something like illustrator and drafting you're own one by one looking up custom card makers for whichever game had the closet format to yours and creating your own.